# How do I merge two similar tags as tag synonyms? (or suggest them for merging)

Tags: support

I noticed two similar tags and I know about the tag-synonym thing but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: You need 2500 rep to do that. You could let another user with 2.5k+ rep about synonyms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its all explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) - it also says, as RegisteredUser said, that you need 2500 rep to do it.

Comment: oh. okay. that's why! thanks :)